# Canceling Timer after x intervals

Tags: c#, timer

I have a timer that's supposed to run x times in 500ms intervals. Currently my code looks something like this:

```
 var i = 0;
 var times = 10;
 timer = new System.Threading.Timer(_ =>
 {
    if (timer == null || i >= times)
        return;

    Console.WriteLine("Run " + i);

    if (i < times - 1)
        i++;
    else
    {
        timer.Dispose();
        timer = null;
    }
 }, null, 500, 500);
```

Is this a reliable way to cancel the timer, if I make sure only one gets created and referenced in the timer variable?

The amount of intervals is variable at run-time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks pretty safe for the disposing of timer.  I would make the i and times variables private and not part of the method.  This creates faster code.  Also, there is a slight possibility that the timer delegate could be running simultaneously on different threads, see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.timer.aspx, so I might use the Interlocked.Increment method.

Maybe something like this:

```
class Foo
{
  volatile int runCount;
  int maxRunCount;
  Timer timer;

  void RunFor(int max)
  {
    maxRunCount = max;
    timer = new System.Threading.Timer(_ =>
    {
      if (timer == null) return;
      Console.WriteLine("Run " + runCount);

      if (Interlocked.Increment(ref runCount) == maxRunCount)
      {
          timer.Dispose();
          timer = null;
      }
    }, null, 500, 500);
  }
}
```

**[EDIT]**

On review of the code, I might throw a lock around the dispose of timer, to prevent race conditions.

```
    if (...)
    {
       lock(this)
       {
          if (timer != null) timer.Dispose();
          timer = null;
       }
     }
```

Comment: You are overdoing it a bit. Once `Dispose` is called, it won't fire again (I checked the disassembled code, and it does indeed ensure that `Dispose` is executed in a thread safe manner).
Also, if you increment runCount at the beginning and then perform the check to Dispose, you won't have race conditions.

Comment: @Johny, you are right in that the `Interlocked.Increment` should take care of any race conditions.  I just felt better placing a lock around it.  I'm cautious when it comes to multi-threading.  But thanks for the oversight.

Comment: I know the feeling! :) Another point is, that you can leave out the "timer = null" part as well as the null check.

Comment: I don't think so.  If the timer delegate takes longer than the interval another delegate is run on different thread.  This is documented behaviour!

Comment: Yeah, that's why I said the check (if it has run out of "counts" and should dispose) should be made at the start of the delegate. That way another won't fire.

Answer (score 1):

You should use the `System.Timers.Timer` class instead...
It supports both `Stop()` and `Start()` methods.

Short example:

```
System.Timers.Timer timer = new System.Timers.Timer();
var i = 0;
var times = 10;


public SetupTimer()
{
    timer.Interval = 500;
    timer.Elapsed += OnTimerElapsed;
    timer.Start();
}

private void OnTimerElapsed(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    // Logic

    if (i > times)
    {
       timer.Stop();
    }
}
```